# Implementing Iterator interface with exception handling

Tags: java, unit-testing, iterator, bufferedreader, factory-pattern

I need to create a class library which enables me to read different files (.dat-files with different data representations inside them) and create objects with their content (for every line one object).

I also have to create a unit test which starts the reading of the file, so I dont have to read to whole file first and save the content in an array. I want to use the factory pattern.

Here is my implementation of the class that implements the Iterator-Interface

```
package klassenbibliothek;
public class MyReader implements Iterator<Object>
{
    BufferedReader reader;
    MyReader(BufferedReader myReader)
    { 
        reader = myReader;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() // aus Stackoverflow, von mir abgeändert
    {
        try {
            return reader.ready();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String next() 
    {
        //return SubstancesFileObjectCreator(reader.readLine());
        try {
            return reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            // return null;
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: why do I get this error message "finally block does not complete normally"? I am not returning something, I am just throwing an exception.

I want to use the methods hasNext() and next() in my unit test, so that the unit test can controll when it starts to read the file. The unit test is in a different package.

Here are my other classes:
class AbstractFileObjectCreator

```
package klassenbibliothek;
public abstract class AbstractFileObjectCreator
{
    public abstract AbstractFileObject createFileObject(String line);
}
```

class SubstancesFileObjectCreator

```
package klassenbibliothek;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SubstancesFileObjectCreator extends AbstractFileObjectCreator
{
    MyReader myReader;

    public void makeReader() throws IOException
    { 
        String dataFileName = "C:/temp/Substances.dat";
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new        FileReader(dataFileName));
        myReader = new MyReader(bReader);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public AbstractFileObject createFileObject(String line)
    {
        AbstractFileObject mySubstance = null;

        String lineValues[] = myReader.next().split("\t");
        if(lineValues[0].equals("R"))
        {
            boolean dutyToDeclare_local;
            boolean isUnwanted_local;
            boolean isProhibited_local;
            boolean isReach_local;
            boolean isDeleted_local;
            boolean isHidden_local;
            String nodeidRaw = lineValues[1];
            float nodeid = Float.parseFloat(nodeidRaw);
            String casNrRaw = lineValues[2];
            String euIndexCodeRaw = lineValues[3];
            String einecsCodeRaw = lineValues[4];
            String dutyToDeclareRaw = lineValues[5];
            if(dutyToDeclareRaw.equals(1))
            {
                dutyToDeclare_local = true;
            } 
            else
            {
                dutyToDeclare_local = false;
            }
            String isUnwantedRaw = lineValues[6];
            if(isUnwantedRaw.equals("1"))
            {
                isUnwanted_local = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isUnwanted_local = false;
            }
            String isProhibitedRaw = lineValues[7];
            if(isProhibitedRaw.equals("1"))
            {
                isProhibited_local = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isProhibited_local = false;
            }
            String isReachRaw = lineValues[8];
            if(isReachRaw.equals("1"))
            {
                isReach_local = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isReach_local = false;
            }
            String isDeletedRaw = lineValues[9];
            if(isDeletedRaw.equals("1"))
            {
                isDeleted_local = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isDeleted_local = false;
            }
            String isHiddenRaw = lineValues[10];
            if(isHiddenRaw.equals("1"))
            {
                isHidden_local = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isHidden_local = false;
            }
            mySubstance = new Substance(nodeid, casNrRaw, euIndexCodeRaw, einecsCodeRaw, dutyToDeclare_local, isUnwanted_local, isProhibited_local, isReach_local, isDeleted_local, isHidden_local);
            // und weiter...
        }
        else
        {
            String languageCode = lineValues[1];
            String name = lineValues[2];
            // Synonym-Objekt erzeugen und zu Substance-Objekt hinzufügen
            Synonym newSynonym = new Synonym(languageCode, name);
            mySubstance.addAppendix(newSynonym);
            while(myReader.hasNext())
            {
                String lineValues_synonyms[] = myReader.next().split("\t");
                String lineValuesZero = lineValues_synonyms[0];
                if(lineValuesZero.equals("R"))
                {
                    break; // nicht so gut glaube ich!!!
                }
                String languageCode_next = lineValues_synonyms[1];
                String name_next = lineValues_synonyms[2];
                Synonym newSynonym_next = new Synonym(languageCode_next, name_next);
                mySubstance.addAppendix(newSynonym_next);
            }

        }
        return mySubstance;
    }
}
```

class AbstractFileObject

```
package klassenbibliothek;

public abstract class AbstractFileObject
{
    boolean isDeleted;

    public AbstractFileObject(boolean isDeleted)
    {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public boolean getIsDeleted()
    {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public abstract void addAppendix(Object newAppendix);
}
```

class Substance

```
public class Substance extends AbstractFileObject
{
    private float nodeid;
    private String casNr;
    private String euIndexCode;
    private String einecsCode;
    private boolean dutyToDeclare;
    private boolean isUnwanted;
    private boolean isProhibited;
    private boolean isReach;
    private boolean isDeleted;
    private boolean isHidden;

    private ArrayList<Synonym> synonymList;

    public Substance(float nodeid, String casNr, String euIndexCode, String einecsCode,
        boolean dutyToDeclare, boolean isUnwanted, boolean isProhibited, boolean isReach,
        boolean isDeleted, boolean isHidden)
    {
        super(isDeleted);
        this.nodeid = nodeid;
        this.casNr = casNr;
        this.euIndexCode = euIndexCode;
        this.einecsCode = einecsCode;
        this.dutyToDeclare = dutyToDeclare;
        this.isUnwanted = isUnwanted;
        this.isProhibited = isProhibited;
        this.isReach = isReach;
        //this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
        this.isHidden = isHidden;
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

class Synonym

```
package klassenbibliothek;

public class Synonym
{
    private String languageCode;
    private String name;

    public Synonym(String languageCode, String name)
    {
        this.languageCode = languageCode;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLanguageCode()
    {
        return languageCode;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

unit test

```
package klassenbibliothek.test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SubstancesTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        //fail("Not yet implemented");
        long startTimeNanos = System.nanoTime();

        /*
         * While... iterator over data file
         */
    }
}
```

Am I using the factory pattern in the right way? I'm very confused.

Comment: *"why do I get this error message "finally block does not complete normally"? I am not returning something, I am just throwing an exception."* And throwing an exeception prevents finally from completing normally. Do you know what an exeception is? Do you know what a `finally` block is?

Comment: you are overriding the method `next` of `Iterator` if you have to always throw an exception whatever happens, then the method next should `throw` an exception `NoSuchElementException` then again it will not be overriding the `Iterator` class's `next` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A finally block **always** executes if there is a try-block before it. So yours always throws a NoSuchElementException().

```
finally
        {
            // return null;
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
```

You should do something in it and not throw an Exception.

Comment: ok that makes sense. But i don't know that i should add in the finally block. I have to use exception handlung, and the method hast to return a String, so what should i put in the finally block which  doesen't conflict with the meanung of the next() and hasNext() method?

Comment: Like Necreaux said: Finally blocks usually are for cleanup. Close stuff, maybe log something, ... you also dont need to use a finally-block! They are optional. I assume you are german as the packages have german names. If so, this is an excellent reading about try-catch-finally and java in general: [Java ist auch eine Insel](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_06_001.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Finally blocks are for cleanup. They should not specifically throw exceptions like that.  Move the exception throwing out of the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the throw exception from the finally block and put it in catch block or some other place. Finally block is to release resources that you might be using in your program.